# Assign User to any Shop in Laravel Relationship?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, foreign-keys

In laravel, I have 3 table

```
 User // for Authentication and Create Another User Once logged in
 Expense
 Shop
```

**My Purpose-** I want user can register and Also, can create another user when they logged in And Can `assign` user to another `Shop` as they want..

And Only `User in the Same Shop` Can see their `Expense`..

// My `User` Table

```
<pre>
   Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('shop_id')->nullable();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id')->nullable();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
</pre>
```

// My `Expense` Table

```
<pre>
    Schema::create('expenses', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->date('date');
        $table->string('description');
        $table->double('amount');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');
    });
</pre>
```

// My `Shop` Table

```
<pre>
     Schema::create('shops', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('expense_id')->nullable();
        $table->unsignedBigInteger('user_id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('description');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->foreign('expense_id')->references('id')->on('expenses');         
        $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users');         
    });
</pre>
```

// My User Model

```
<pre>
   public function expense()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Expense::class);
    }


    public function shop()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(\App\Shop::class, 'user_id');
    }
</pre>
```

// My Expense Model

```
<pre>
class Expense extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['date', 'description', 'amount', 'user_id', 'shop_id'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\User::class);  
    }

}
</pre>
```

// My Shop Model

```
<pre>
class Shop extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['name', 'description', 'expense_id', 'shop_id'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\User::class, 'user_id');
    }

}
</pre>
```

// Expense Controller

```
<pre>
 public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $expense = Expense::with(['user'])->get();

        return ExpenseResource::collection($expense);

        // dd(auth()->user());
    }

    public function create(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'date' => 'required',
            'description' => 'required',
            'amount' => 'required',

        ]);

        $expense = new Expense();
        $expense->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $expense->date = $request->date;
        $expense->description = $request->description;
        $expense->amount = $request->amount;
        $expense->save();

        return new ExpenseResource($expense);
    }
</pre>
```

// in My UserController

```
<pre>
public function index()
    {
        $users = User::all();
        $shops = Shop::all();
        return view('user', compact('users', 'shops'));
        // return UserResource::collection($users);
    }

    public function create(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required',
        ]);

        $user = new user();
        $user->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $user->name = $request->name;
        $user->email = $request->email;
        $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);
        $user->save();

        return new UserResource($user);
    }
</pre>
```

Is it make sense?

Any idea, thanks..

Comment: This is far too broad. Creating a User requires a form, model, route and controller for doing so, assigning to a `Store` requires linking/relationship between the models/sql, viewing specific related records also requires routing and custom constraining logic, etc. etc.  What have you tried? What *specific* error are you running into? Please show your attempt first; Stackoverflow isn't a code writing service. This is definitely doable, but you'll need to make an attempt first.

Comment: i tried can not limit user to see only their Shop.. @TimLewis

Comment: If you've tried something, show what you've tried; it will definitely be easier to help when we know the specific problem and what's causing it.

Comment: What u need to see? Model or Controller @TimLewis

Comment: Whatever code is relevant to your issue. Likely just the Model and Controller, yes, but if there's something else you think is pertinent, include that too. Always try to provide code in your questions.

Comment: @TimLewis i updated my question bro, pls take a look.

Comment: Much better! So currently, you're simply returning all `Expense` records, regardless of the `User` associated and their linked `Shop`. So what you'll need to do is check the current user, and constrain the returned `Expense` records to only be included if their `User` is in the same `Shop`. I'll write a quick example.

Comment: @TimLewis i'll look forward your example, bro xD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments, you'll need to check the current `User` and constrain the returned `Expense` records to only those that 1) have a `User` and 2) match the same `Store` as the current `User`. This can be done in a single `whereHas()` clause:

```
public function index(Request $request) {
  $user = auth()->user(); // If using default `Auth` logic.

  $expenses = Expense::whereHas('user', function($subQuery) use($user){
    return $subQuery->where('shop_id', '=', $user->shop_id);
  })->with(['user'])->get();

  return ExpenseResource::collection($expenses);
}
```

What `->whereHas()` does is constrains the query fetching your `Expense` models to respect the logic you pass it, which in this case is only include `Expense` models that have a `user` that has the same `shop_id` as the currently logged in `User`.

Note:If the current `User` does not have a `Shop`, it might return unexpected results, but you could protect the route to only allow a `User` with a `Shop` to access it, etc.

Comment: i dont understant about `User`, Can i change it?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you're asking. And my bad, argument would be `user` (lowercase), not `User`.

Comment: still, it's not solve
maeby i have problem with `create shop`, How can i share image with u? i want to share my screenshot

Comment: It's likely your relationship logic. You shouldn't have both `user_id` on `shops`, and `shop_id` on `users`. A `User` should `belongTo()` a `Shop`, while a `Shop` should `hasMany()` `User`s. Also, does the `Expense` model have a `shop` relationship? Cause you could just query that directly.

Comment: Should i delete it?

Comment: `Expense` doesnt have `shop` relationship, bro

Comment: Just sort your relationships out. You say "User in the Same Shop", but you don't support a `one-to-many` relationship (at least I don't think you do; you didn't post your `User` model). You can link `Expense` directly to `Shop` if you want (again, `one-to-many`, as a `Shop` likely has many `Expense`s) but yeah. There's definitely some issues there still. Edit: You suggest it does (or should) by having a `shop_id` on your `expenses` table.

Comment: Sorry, im new to relationship, i'll post my `User Model`

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand your relationships... The way you have it setup now, a `User` can have many `Shop` records, but a `Shop` can't have more than 1 `User`, so this whole "In the same Shop" is a situation that can never happen... Unless you refactor to a `many-to-many`, where `User`s can have multiple `Shop`s, and `Shop`s have multiple `User`s.

Comment: Did you setup the database? You'll need to fix that first; iron out the "relational" part of RDBS, get your columns/pivot tables (if required), etc. figured out first. Like I said, the way you have your columns currently, there will never be a case where two users have the same shop.

Comment: How can i share screenshot with u, do u have any social media or what, bro?

Comment: Not exactly, no. But you should be able to include a screenshot in your question.

Comment: You can include it, but I won't be able to do much with it. You need to engineer your database in a way that supports correct relations. If you need help with that, a new question might be the way to go; ignore the Laravel part and focus on getting your tables correctly structured.

Comment: yeah, its okay bro, just give me some  as the way u can..  anyway i'll update my question pls take a look..