# Got issues with Assigning User to any Shop in Laravel

Tags: laravel, foreign-keys

I have an issue with assign user to any Shop. i created `Shop A` and `Shop B` and want to assign user to each shop. Its work fine, when im assign any user to `Shop A`. however, when i try assign user to `Shop B` , user alway got in to `Shop A` not `Shop B`.

// My `User` Model

```php
public function shop()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\Shop::class, 'user_id');
}
```

// My `Shop` Model

```php
public function user()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\App\User::class, 'user_id');
}
```

// My `UserController`

```php
public function index()
{
    $users = User::all();
    $shops = Shop::all();
    // return view('user', compact('users', 'shops'));
    return UserResource::collection($users);
}

public function create(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    $user = new user();
    $user->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $user->name = $request->name;
    $user->email = $request->email;
    $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);
    $user->save();

    return new UserResource($user);
}
```

// My `User.blade.php` Code

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

    <div class="container" style="width: 50%">

        <h2>Create User</h2>
        @if ($errors->any())
            <div class="alert alert-danger">
                <ul>
                    @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                        <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                    @endforeach
                </ul>
            </div>
        @endif

        <form action="user" method="POST">
            @csrf
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" >
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
            </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                <label for="shop">Shop</label>
                <select name="shops" class="form-control">
                    @foreach($shops as $shop)
                        <option value="{{ $shop->id }}">
                            {{ $shop->name }}
                        </option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Am i doing something wrong with `Relationship`?

Comment: I can't see where you assign users to shop in your code you pasted in the question.

Comment: Your relations are a bit confusing, since the `User` `belongTo` `Shop`, why doesn't the `User` has a foreign key `shop_id` ? I think you reversed the logic there. What you meant is 1 shop belongs to only 1 user and 1 user can have many shops ? right ?

Comment: @zlatan sorry, i forget to add it. i updated my post, pls take a look.

Comment: @N69S can i take a look at my this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57661443/assign-user-to-any-shop-in-laravel-relationship

Comment: @N69S its all i want to do..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two distinct relation from the `Shop` model to the `User` model.

// Shop Model

```php
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\App\User::class);
}

public function owner()
{
    return $this->belongTo(\App\User::class);
}
```

If in your controller you want to assign the shop to the user created

```php
public function create(Request $request)
{
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    $user = new user();
    $user->user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $user->shop_id = $request->shops;
    $user->name = $request->name;
    $user->email = $request->email;
    $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);
    $user->save();

    return new UserResource($user);
}
```

For the `User` Model, you need to define the two different relation with `Shop` Model

```php
public function shop()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(\App\Shop::class); //remove the foreign key or change it to 'shop_id'
}

public function ownedShops()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Shop::class);
}
```